# Initialize classes of dynamic types

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, reflection, activator

I have a method where I need to dynamically change the class used depending on user settings as below, class dEnvelope needs to have its properties initialized as well to fill all subclasses and used in the same manner, all these different Year classes have the exact structure but the business logic differs in their internal methods

```
    dynamic dEnvelope;

    if (UserYear==2013)
        dEnvelope = new Years.Y2013.DataEnvelope();
    else
        dEnvelope = new Years.Y2012.DataEnvelope();


    dEnvelope.InnerClass= Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(dEnvelope.InnerClass));
```

However I receive an error when executing the Activator.CreateInstance line

> {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: typeName"}

Am I missing something about the usage of the dynamic type? Is there a better way of dynamically picking the correct class to be used on run time?

Answer (score 0):

I think You should first Initialize the variable of the class "Years" through Constructor and the you should try to access the method. i.e.  `dEnvelope = new Years().Y2013.DataEnvelope();`

And also please show your code snippet for better understanding.

Comment: Years.Y2013 and Years.Y2012 are namespaces not classes.

Comment: it is null pointer; Type.GetType("namespace.qualified.TypeName") only works when the type is found in either mscorlib.dll or the currently executing assembly. Please check your code

Comment: dEnvelope.InnerClass= Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(dEnvelope.InnerClass));

Comment: You can also use the other method - 
Type myClassType = Type.GetType("TypeName,DllName"); Just check through it.

Comment: How is this comment different than my code above, did you really read the question?

Comment: I read the question- I am saying that Please see the error would be in the line dEnvelope.InnerClass= Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(dEnvelope.InnerClass));
and change by the another method. The  dEnvelope variable is not intializing. Dat's null is comining.

Comment: My question clearly has "I receive an error when executing the Activator.CreateInstance line", and I cant use TypenName, type is dynamic

Comment: In your code  dEnvelope.InnerClass is null; that you are passing as a parameter in  Type.GetType(dEnvelope.InnerClass); Here you have to change. This is the error. GetType method needs string type value that is null;